# How do I add functions to auto-mapped SqlAlchemy classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I was wondering if it is possible to use SqlAlchemy's `automap_base()` in the following way:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# automap base
Base = automap_base()

# pre-declare User for the 'user' table
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def greet(self):
        return 'Hello {}!'.format(self.name)

    def add_address(self, address):
        '''Utilizes the auto reflected relationship to add
           a new address with a proper user_id to table "addresses"'''
        self.address_collection.append(address)

# reflect
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydatabase.db")
# only to generate attributes and relationships
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```

So I would like to reflect the data and the relationships from the database, but extend the auto-generated class with additional functionality. Is it possible?

Comment: I think the example you've shown should work, does it not? Looks like http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#specifying-classes-explicitly

Comment: I get the following error: sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError:Mapper Mapper|User|user could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'user'

Comment: Then the database table doesn't have a primary key. You can override a column as in the previous link I sent, adding `primary_key=True` for the ORM.